# Is it possible to change dom-element property types? (Number, String etc.)

Tags: javascript, dom, properties

Consider an input field

```
<input type="number" id="output" disabled="true">
```

is something like this possible ?

```
var output = Document.getElementById("output");
output.value = Number(0);
```

I tested it and it has no effect (+= operator is still concating strings). Is there a way to change the variable type of a dom-element property?

What exactly happens in the line

```
Document.getElementById("output").value = Number(0);
```

and why does it have no effect on the type?

Does this apply to Dom-objects only or are there other cases that this invariability also applies to (or were I can actively define it for a variable)?

PS: I know I can simply use a temporary variable to avoid problems like this in general, but I want to know why the DOM property is unaffected by `output.value = Number(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning a value directly to a DOM element attribute you should use the setAttribute function of the element.

```
var output = Document.getElementById("output");
output.setAttribute('value',Number(0));
```

> why does it have no effect on the type?

The DOM element's attributes are part of the HTML and because of the HTML structure all the attribute values should always be quoted (https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html#h-4.4), therefore for any value that you set for a property it will be stored as a string.

This means that even if you're explicitly giving the value Number(0) for the atribute 'value' at the end it will be stored in the HTML structure like this:

```
<input type="number" id="output" disabled="true" value="0"/>
```

And as you can see it is quoted, this is the string representation of the attribute value, for a 0 the string representation is "0", if you try to set an attribute with another type e.g an object, you will have something like this.

```
//setting a custom attribute the value: {a:10}
document.getElementById('output').setAttribute('myattr',{a:10})
```

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="output" disabled="true" myattr="[object Object]">
```

[image]